# Split the archive into volumes with the maximum volume file size

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to create an archive test.zip, breaking it into volumes with the maximum volume file size

```
import os, zipfile

def zip_dir(path, zp):
    for entry in os.scandir(path):
        zp.write(entry.path)
        if entry.is_dir(follow_symlinks=False):
            zip_dir(entry.path, zp)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    max_size = 1024  # ?
    with zipfile.ZipFile('test.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zp:
        zip_dir('libs', zp)
        zip_dir('.idea', zp)
```

Comment: What's meant with `max_size = 1024`? File Size, Number of Files or?

Comment: Python's `zipfile` module does not support multi-file archives. From [the `zipfile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html): `This module does not currently handle multi-disk ZIP files.` Seeing that you're using the module to compress already existing files on your disk, why not call an external tool instead?